# Query with four tables in ASP.net using lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have a web page that allows user to sign petitions, in the user detail page I want to display the petitions the user has signed, including the petition image. The image is specific to the category of the petition.

I have a category model that holds the image

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string catImage { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Cause> Causes { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a cause model that links to the Category through CategoryID

```
public class Cause
{
    public int CauseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdOn { get; set; }
    public int Target { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Then a signature model that links the Cause to the User

```
public class Signature
{
    public int SignatureID { get; set; }
    public int CauseID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime signedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Cause Cause { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

And finally a user model

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserImage { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }
}
```

On the user details page I am trying to display a table with a list of all the petitions the user has signed.  I have been able to show the name and the date shown, but not the images.
I would really appreciated any help.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide examples of what do you have already (code)

Comment: You are probably missing a . Include() of your Category class. 
First, show us your request.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't actually have anything to show. I am really new to doing this and it is really confusing for me.